# Pine Script How to comparing different types

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

How to get the price value when an event is completed. There are two events:

Crossover of macd_line and signal_line
Lowest price value for the last 13 days
The long position is closed when one of the events occurs

```
lmacdl = crossover(macd_line, signal_line)
lowestLow = lowest(low, 13)

stoplong = max (macdl, lowestLow)

if  (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit ("Sl_Buy", "Buy", stop=stoplong)
```

But an error comes out: Cannot call 'min' with 'arg_2' = series [bool]. The argument should be of type: series [float]

So comparing different types. Therefore, the question is: how to get the specific price value when the crossover event (macd_line, signal_line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable with the `var` keyword. Then update its value when the crossover event takes place and keep its original value if otherwise. So, it will hold the latest macd line value until a new crossover event takes place.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

var my_macdl = 0.0
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
my_macdl := ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) ? macdLine : my_macdl
plot(my_macdl)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
To keep the price value use the following code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

var macd_price = 0.0
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macd_price := ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) ? close: macd_price
```

It will store the `close` price.

Comment: Vitruvius, thank you for you answer! But I need to keep price value, when crossover(macdLine, signalLine) but not a MACD value

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit.

Comment: I understend!  my_macdl := ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) ? price : my_macdl

Comment: I just added a code sample for you.